# Can we say normal stress and pressure are the same?

Tags: pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics

Now if your Ans is yes then I have one more  question to ask.
.ie don't u agree that we should not say stress as a tensor of 2nd order rather only tangential stress as tensor of 2nd order and normal stress as tensor of 0 order or scalar .

Comment: The answer to your question is already in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286492/pressure-in-the-stress-tensor?rq=1

Comment: That means normal stress and pressure r same , pls confirm.

Comment: The normal stress is the triple $\sigma_{ii}, i=1,2,3$. Pressure is $1/3$ of the sum of these three numbers. In general, they are different.

Comment: Pressure is isotropic and an additive part of the stress tensor, but the stress tensor itself is not necessarily isotropic.  So, no, pressure is not the same thing as the stress tensor.